# Words returns wrong output when a String has apostrophes in it

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to split a String into a list of words

`split_string :: String -> [Word]`

`split_string x = words x`

"Functional Programming is Fun, isn’t it?" should give me back:

["Functional","Programming","is","Fun,","isn’t","it?"]

but it returns me this instead:
["Functional","Programming","is","Fun,","isn\8217t","it?"]

How can I avoid problem with the apostrophes problem?
I am new to Haskell so sorry in advance if this is a stupid question.

Comment: This seem to be not a standard ASCII `'` character but some unicode one.

Comment: This is not *wrong* this is simply the *representation* of the string. Note that there is a difference between the *content* of a string, and its representation. The double quotes are for example also part of the representation.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: this is an *apostrophe*, not a single quote: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Well, when we type in English we use it in place of apostrophe.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: yes, apparently in English the *typesetter apostrophe* is `’` and the *typewriter apostrophe* is `'` :)

Comment: didn't know that...but how could I avoid it showing like this and not as it was inserted ?

Comment: @AmilaBečirović: the string representation will escape most characters that are non-visible ASCII to avoid confusion (since this character looks closely to the single quote `'`). If you `putStrLn` then you print the *content* of a string: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem in some cases it would cause confusion, but I think it's safe to say that the horribly-looking escaping when just about any non-English text is displayed causes much more confusion. I don't think confusion is the result the Haskell standard opted for escaping all non-ASCII – encoding-compatibility is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a common misunderstanding about what Haskell's `Show` mechanism is there for. Many beginners think it is supposed to yield pretty visualisations, but actually its purpose is specifically to generate representations that are *valid Haskell code*.

That means in particular that they shouldn't contain stuff that would cause an error if you copy&paste it back into a Haskell file.
For example, consider the string `you tried to show "something" on the terminal`. If GHCi displayed this as

```
"you tried to show "something" on the terminal"
```

that would incur a parse error. The quotation marks need to be escaped:

```
"you tried to show \"something\" on the terminal"
```

and that's the form that the `Show String` instance generates.

Generally, the representation is not unique. For example

```
"you tried to show \34something\34 on the terminal"
```

would also work, where `\34` is the ASCII character code for the `"` symbol. This form can in fact be used for *any* characters:

```
Prelude> "\72\101\108\108\111\44\32\87\111\114\108\100"
"Hello, World"
```

Of course it's silly to do that for *all* characters, but the Haskell standard plays it safe in the sense that all non-ASCII characters are displayed in the escaped way:

```
Prelude> "Amila Bečirović"
"Amila Be\269irovi\263"
```

The advantage is that you're safe from quirks that could be introduced by incompatible character encodings – in the early 2000s this would often happen when Webpages used language-specific 8-bit encodings. By now this [shouldn't really be an issue anymore](http://utf8everywhere.org/).

As Willem Van Onsem wrote, you can always just raw-dump a string with `putStrLn`, which doesn't escape anything – though this isn't directly applicable to a *list* of strings.

For more flexibility, you can opt for a different `Show` class that doesn't have this behaviour, such as from the [`pragmatic-show` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pragmatic-show):

```
Prelude> import qualified Text.Show.Pragmatic as SP
Prelude SP> SP.print ["Functional","Programming","is","Fun,","isn’t","it?"]
["Functional","Programming","is","Fun,","isn’t","it?"]
Prelude SP> SP.print "Amila Bečirović"
"Amila Bečirović"
```

Note that this will still escape characters that really are unsafe:

```
Prelude SP> SP.print "bla\34blub"
"bla\"blub"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not the string content. This is the *representation* of a string. If you write `"foo"` for a string literal, then the double quotes are not part of the *content* of the string. These are used to write a string literal.

Normally the [**`Show`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Show) will return for the `show` of an objects a string where the *content* of the string looks like a Haskell expression. This makes it more convenient to later copy paste the value in the code.

You can print the *content* of a string with [**`putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn). For example:

```
Prelude> putStrLn "isn’t"
isn’t
Prelude> putStrLn "isn\8217t"
isn’t
```